# "To live here demands…" vs. "Living here demands…"

Tags: meaning, gerunds, infinitives

> To live here demands extraordinary survival strategies.

Is the above structure common? It's from Planet Earth BBC series. Does the above sentence convey the same meaning as:

> Living here demands extraordinary survival strategies.

Comment: Did you mean "here"?

Comment: And "Living" in the second example sentence?

Comment: I think #1 (the infinitive version) is just about credible in this *exact* context, but in many similar contexts it doesn't work at all well. Most "credible" contexts involve *repeating* the infinitive, to create a parallel "epigrammatic" structure, such as [*To live is to suffer*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+live+is+to+suffer%22) My advice would be to stick to the second ("gerund noun" format) in all contexts, since it will probably always be *acceptable*, and usually much better than the alternative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. May you please extend The answer, What do you mean by 'credible context'?

Comment: I suppose by "most credible contexts" I mean usages that the average native speaker wouldn't think of as "odd" or "awkward" (or even "invalid"). Have a look at [point #2 here:](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm) ***It is not impossible** for an infinitive to appear at the beginning of a sentence as the subject, but **it is more common for an infinitive to appear as a Subject Complement**.* In your specific example I'm sure most native speakers/writers would use the gerund *(#2 - **living here**)*, but ***to live here*** isn't actually "invalid".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Please consider converting you comments to an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is a rare "in order to" case you can only get with the infinitive not the gerund . That's why it works.

Comment: @tchrist : [*To live here would be the greatest thing ever*](https://it.pinterest.com/pin/482940760021646264/) looks like the same basic construction to me, but there's no sense of "in order to" there. And with both OP's and my example, I'd expect gerund ***living here*** to be far more common that infinitive ***to live***.

Answer (score 2):

The two sentences have different perspectives--outside looking in vs. inside.

> To live here demands extraordinary survival strategies.

"To live here" means "in order to live here".  This describes life abstractly **if** you're there.  It also makes an implied comparison ("here" demands extraordinary survival strategies relative to other places).

> Living here demands extraordinary survival strategies.

The continuous form describes the actual, real-time experience.

Comment: The first one means *in order to*, and **THAT'S**  why it's different.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks.  Good point.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, as a native English speaker, the second is slightly better-sounding, what I'd use in conversation, but I don't think one is right or wrong.